# How to find a linear trend from a time series?

Tags: matlab, linear-regression

How would I go about finding a linear trend from a time series?

I know the time series is `y = {y1,...yn}` or for the first case `{1.000000000000000   0.917457418407746   0.683456229182811}`. It's assumed that each element `yi` was sampled at time `ti = i`.

The polynomial it needs to be fitted to is of degree 1.

What I've attempted is below.

```
function [ linCoeffs ] = getLinearTrend(y)

   y = [1.000000000000000,0.917457418407746,0.683456229182811];
   x = ;
   linCoeffs = polyfit(y,x,1);

end
```

It's not much as I'm stumped on what to do for the x value. Normally y would be an input value but for testing I just left it in.

Comment: use something like `x=1:n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you've provided the arguments to `polyfit` in the wrong order. The first argument takes the values of the *x* axis which, in this case, correspond to the sampling times given by *i*. The *second* argument takes the *y* values. So you'd want something like:

```
function linCoeffs = getLinearTrend(y)

   linCoeffs = polyfit(1:size(y,2), y, 1);

end
```

which, given your example *y*, results in:

```
y = [1.000000000000000,0.917457418407746,0.683456229182811];

getLinearTrend(y)
ans =

  -0.15827   1.18351
```

Comment: It should give the result below when the test harness below is used.
linCoeffs =

  -0.158271885408595   1.183514986680709

Comment: @Blitzkayir the arguments were provided in the wrong order. Please try the revised answer. Looks like it's doing what you want now.